# Multiple images as CNN input - cannot reshape array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train CNN to drive a car using 4 images as one input.

This is how my code looks like

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.models import Model


# Loading data
train_data = np.load("/mydrive/Mister_car/training_data-6.npy", allow_pickle=True)
WIDTH = 200
HEIGHT = 160
MODEL_DIR = "/mydrive/Mister_car/model/"

# Load new model
#model = alexnet((WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 9)

model1 = alexnet((WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 9)
model2 = alexnet((WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 9)
model3 = alexnet((WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 9)
model4 = alexnet((WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3), 9)

combined = concatenate([model1.output, model2.output, model3.output, model4.output])
out = Dense(9, activation="softmax")(combined)

model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input, model3.input, model4.input], outputs = out)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
                 loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

# Load existing model
# model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_DIR)

if len(train_data) > 10:
    print("git")
    # Splitting data into a training set and test set
    train = train_data[:]
    test = train_data[:]

    print(train[6][0][0].shape)

    X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
    Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])

    x_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test])#.reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
    y_test = np.array([i[1] for i in test])

    # start training
    model.fit(x=X,
              y=Y,
              epochs=10,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

    # save the whole model
    model.save(MODEL_DIR)
```

This lines causes problem

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])

x_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test])#.reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
y_test = np.array([i[1] for i in test])
```

cannot reshape array of size 200 into shape (4,200,160,3)

Earlier with one image as input I used this:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])

x_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test])#.reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
y_test = np.array([i[1] for i in test])
```

where i[0] is the image and i[1] is a list with keyboard input.

Now i[0] is a list of 4 images and i[1] is a list of 4 lists.
So I added this new dimension, which is for but I get this error. It's very strange for me.
I would be really appreciated for your help.

Comment: Please check if the link, https://www.kaggle.com/c/cdiscount-image-classification-challenge/discussion/41123 is useful. Thanks!